# Data is not being saved in mongdb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-ec2

Hi i am using mongodb and deploying it in AWS. But the data is not properly being saved in the server.

I created many collections but the data is not present inside the collection.

Do i need any other setting . Please let me know

[image]

Comment: Could you specify where exactly in AWS you're deploying your mongodb and also how you're writing/reading data to/from it?

Answer (score 1):

The database named `READ_ME_TO_RECOVER_YOUR_DATA` suggests that you created the mongod server without authentication, and some hackers were able to steal/delete all of your data, and are probably now expecting you to pay some bitcoin to get it back.

I doubt they actually made a backup of your data before deleting it, since they don't actually care about you or your data.

There was a blog post from the MongoDB folks a couple of years ago about how to avoid this:  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/update-how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data

#1 recommendation is to enable authentication.